# Как остановить итерации при пустых ячейках? openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Данный код, на линии переменной `a`и `b` выдает ошибку -> *builtins.TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'*.

Причину я знаю, при итерации столбца '`B`' получается примерно `ws['B'] = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', '', '', '', '', '']` , дело в том что в соседних столбцах больше значений, вот он и идет до конца и пустые ячейки добавляет.

Как остановить итерации когда доходит до пустых ячеек?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

values1 = [row[0].value for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=2)]
a = datetime.datetime.date(min(values1))

values2 = [row[0].value for row in ws['C3:C7']]
b = datetime.datetime.date(max(values2))

i = a
col=4
while i <= b:
    ws.cell(row=2, column=col).value = i
    i = i + relativedelta(months = 1)
    col += 1

wb.save('Test2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Данный вариант удаляет значения None: `filter(None, ws['A'])`

Есть ли будут варианты остановки итерации при пустых ячейках тоже пишите.

```
values1 = list(filter(None, [row[0].value for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=2)]))
a = datetime.datetime.date(min(values1))

values2 = list(filter(None, [row[0].value for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=3)]))
b = datetime.datetime.date(max(values2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать условия в генераторе списков:

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,5,'','']
res = [x for x in lst if x] #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Однако, и это решение, и ваше решение с `filter` не останавливает итерацию, а прогоняет ее полностью, и обрабатывает уже полученный список. Если вы хотите именно остановить итерацию по условию, то от никуда не деться от конструкции вида:

```
for x in lst:
    if not x:
        break
    res.append(x)
```